# Adding cooldown to script

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)

EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(1)

    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1) do
        PressAndReleaseKey("lalt")
            Sleep(15000)
end
end
```

I have this script to press Alt when I left click, But I don't want it to happen every time.

I'd like to add a 15 second "cooldown" so the script won't repeat within 15 seconds.

The sleep function I added runs before the PressAndReleaseKey.

How can I swap those two around?

Comment: Do you want to simulate LAlt 15 seconds after you pressed LMB?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff No I'd like to simulate Lalt instantly after pressing LMB but I don't want LMB to trigger Lalt again for the next 15 seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
local prev_time = -math.huge

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      local this_time = GetRunningTime()
      if this_time - prev_time > 15000 then
         prev_time = this_time
         PressKey("lalt")
         Sleep(50)
         ReleaseKey("lalt")
      end
   end
end
```